# Ignore the result of a filter commands on non-zero exit code in neovim

Tags: neovim, filter

In neovim, I created this very simple command to run my javascript code through [prettierd](https://github.com/fsouza/prettierd) on save.

```
:command! Prettier normal mz:%!prettierd %<CR>'zzz

au BufWritePre *.js :Prettier
```

This works reasonably well (and compared to the plugins I have tried so far, this only touches the file once instead of twice which has quite an impact on the feedback loop of my tests).

But if the file has some serious issues, e.g. mismatching brackets or the like, pretterd exits with a non-zero exit code and an error message, which now replaces my buffer contents.

Can I get the filter to keep the original content on non-zero exit codes? Or do I need to handle that in shell scripts?

Comment: Hi, welcome. You could try to redirect the error stream with `prettier 2> /dev/null`. However, I'm not quite sure your question belongs to this site as it's not about using vim *per se*.

Comment: wrap it into a shell script, that always returns `true`

Comment: @Biggybi I would argue that it is a question about vim, as my question is primarily about, can I get vim to not replace my buffer with an error message when the script fails. If the answer to that question is "no", the answer is still an answer to a vim question (but not the answer I'm hoping for). In that case, I will need to proceed in a non-vim way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can check the exit code of an external command spawned with `!` in the [`v:shell_error`](https://vimhelp.org/eval.txt.html#v%3Ashell_error) special variable.

For instance, you can use that to check the error status of the external command and then use the [`:undo`](https://vimhelp.org/undo.txt.html#%3Aundo) command to revert the filter action.

This is easier to do in a function:

```
function! Prettier()
  let save_cursor = getcurpos()
  silent %!prettierd %
  if v:shell_error != 0
    undo
    echomsg 'Prettier failed.'
  endif
  call setpos('.', save_cursor)
endfunction

au BufWritePre *.js call Prettier()
```